# Count the number of times something showed up in the top 36 rows

Tags: matlab, count

I have a cell of size 1x7 where each cell inside of that is 365x5xN in which each N is a different location (siteID). It is already sorted according to column 5 (the columns are Lat, Lon, siteID, date, and data).
(The data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li3hh1nvt11vok5/4YGfwStQlo. Variable in question is PM25)

I want to go through the entire 1x7 cell and, looking at only the top 36 rows (basically, the top 10 percentile), count the number of times each date shows up. In other words, I want to know on which days the data value fell in the top 10 percentile.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I can't get my mind around how to approach this issue --> counting across all these cells and spitting out a quantity for each day of the year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a sorted cell array, you may use this -

```
%%// Get all the dates for all the rows in sorted cell array
all_dates = [];
for k1=1:size(sorted_cell,2)
    all_dates = [all_dates reshape(cell2mat(sorted_cell{1,k1}(:,4,:)),1,[])];
end
all_unique_dates = unique(all_dates);
all_out = [num2cell(all_unique_dates)' num2cell(zeros(numel(all_unique_dates),1))];%%//'

%%// Get all the dates for the first 36 rows in sorted cell array
dates = [];
for k1=1:size(sorted_cell,2)
    dates = [dates reshape(cell2mat(sorted_cell{1,k1}(1:36,4,:)),1,[])];
end

%%// Get unique dates and their counts
unique_dates = unique(dates);
count = histc(dates, unique_dates);

%%// As output create a cell array with the first column as dates 
%%// and the second column as the counts
out = [num2cell(unique_dates)' num2cell(count)']

%%// Get all the dates and the corresponding counts. 
%%// Thus many would still have counts as zeros.
all_out(ismember(all_unique_dates,unique_dates),:)=out;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works very well. I have a question though. I get 258 days. Is that because any day that is zero has been omitted?

Comment: Would it be possible to keep all the days because I'm going to plot them with days along the x-axis and having gaps would make that more complicated.

Comment: @shizishan Yes, most probably because we are selecting only the first 36 rows. So, you still want to select from the first 36 rows, but get all the dates, just for the plots?

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. I'm not familiar with coding yet so your comments helped show me some methods of thinking through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Often when something looks tricky from the outside, it's easier to start from the inside instead. How can we get the top dates from a single array?

```
dates = unique(array(1:35,4));
```

Now, how to do that for each cell? A loop is always straightforward, but this is a pretty simple function, so let's use the one-liner:

```
datecell = cellfun(@(x) unique(x(1:35,4)), cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Now we have a just the dates we want, for each cell. If there's no need to keep them separated, let's just stick them all together into one big array:

```
dates = cell2mat(datecell);
dates = unique(dates);  % in case there are any duplicates
```

---

If you want to actually *count* each date as well (it's a little unclear), it might be a little too involved for an anonymous function, so we could either write our own function to pass to `cellfun`, or just cop out and stick it in a loop:

```
dates = {};
counts = {};
for ii = 1:length(cellarray)
    [dates{ii}, ~, idx] = unique(cellarray{ii}(1:35,4));
    counts{ii} = accumarray(idx, 1);
end
```

Now, those cell arrays may contain duplication, so we'll have to combine the counts where necessary in a similar way:

```
dates = cell2mat(dates);
counts = cell2mat(counts);
[dates, ~, idx] = unique(dates);
counts = accumarray(idx, counts);  % add the counts of duplicated dates together
```

Note that re-assigning different data to the same variable names like this isn't particularly good practice - I'm just feeling exceptionally lazy tonight, and coming up with good, descriptive names is hard ;)